# Is it possible to derive the indexPath if you know the row?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, nsindexpath

Okay, I'm going to try to break this down as simply as I am able. I have a tableView in a ViewController. I have two prototype cells for the table. I am reusing the cells multiple times to populate the table.

In one of the cells, I've added gesture recognizer to the `label` through which I'm making a `textField` visible on place of the label and hiding the `label`. Now I want the labels text to change to what I've entered in the `textField` when I'm done using the `textField` and hit the return key. So i implemented the `UITextFieldDelegate` protocol in the `viewController`. I've also added tags to each of the textFields in the cell so that I know what `textField` is returning and what row the textField is in.

Basically, what I want to know is if there is any way to get the indexPath if I already know the indexPath.row?

For the gesture recognizers, i was able to work around this issue by getting the indexPath from the tapped location:

```
func genderTapped(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {

        let tapLocation = sender.locationInView(self.profileInfoTable)
        let indexPath = self.profileInfoTable.indexPathForRowAtPoint(tapLocation)

        let cell = self.profileInfoTable.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath!) as! editUserDataCell
        cell.savedUserInput.hidden = true
        cell.userDetailTextfield.becomeFirstResponder()
        cell.userDetailTextfield.hidden = false
        cell.userDetailTextfield.text = cell.savedUserInput.text!            
    }
```

I need the `indexPath` so that I can refer to the elements contained within a cell. Can anyone offer any insights? Has anybody tried a similar approach? Is there any way I can access the cell by just using the row?

Comment: How you set the `tag to each of the textFields`?

Comment: For accessing an UITableView row, you always need both an index of a section and an index of a row within that section. So if your also know the section you need to access, it can have a simple answer. If you only have one section it your tableView, its index is of course 0.

Comment: @pkc456 I set the tags in the cellForRowAtIndexPath function

Comment: @pedrouan I'm just maintaining one section

Comment: My suggestion is to change the label to button, and add target to it to hide or show the textfield. Then set `UITextFieldDelegate ` to your cell. If you want to communicate your cell with tableView. Add a weak reference of your controller to the cell class or use closure is good choice.

Comment: @Jobs, In case you 've to manage multiple section, then please have a [look at this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39122340/988169)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are able to get the indexPath inside the `GestureMethod` then you can create one instance property of type `NSIndexPath` store its value inside that Gesture's method and later used the indexPath inside `textFieldShouldReturn` delegate method, something like this.

```
var selectedIndexPath: NSIndexPath?

func genderTapped(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {

    let tapLocation = sender.locationInView(self.profileInfoTable)
    self.selectedIndexPath = self.profileInfoTable.indexPathForRowAtPoint(tapLocation)

    let cell = self.profileInfoTable.cellForRowAtIndexPath(self.selectedIndexPath!) as! editUserDataCell
    cell.savedUserInput.hidden = true
    cell.userDetailTextfield.becomeFirstResponder()
    cell.userDetailTextfield.hidden = false
    cell.userDetailTextfield.text = cell.savedUserInput.text!
}
```

Now use this `self.selectedIndexPath` inside `UITextFieldDelegate` method.

**Edit:** From your question's comment you have told that you have just one `Section` so you can also create `indexPath` from that `textField`'s `tag` this way.

```
func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    let indexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: textField.tag, inSection: 0)
    //Or You can use self.selectedIndexPath also 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In case of single or **multiple sections**, the below code will work

In your `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, set the tag as below:-

```
let tag = indexPath.section*100 + indexPath.row

cell.savedUserInput.tag = tag
cell.userDetailTextfield.tag = tag
```

In your textfield delegate method, get the indexPath as follows:-

```
func genderTapped(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
let textfieldObject = sender as! UITextField 
let sectionTag = textfieldObject.tag % 100
let rowTag = textfieldObject.tag / 100

let indexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: rowTag.tag, inSection: sectionTag)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

***Disclaimer:** This is not an answer to the literal question asked here, but it might provide an simpler solution to OP's goal.*

Unless you need to do something in addition to what you described in your question it seems to me that a much easier solution would be not to use labels at all but in stead just use an `UITextField` and set it's `enabled` property to false when you want it to act like an label.

You can subclass the `UITextField` if you need the styling to change when the mode changes.

Comment: interesting, I hadn't thought of that approach.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the row number which you are accessing and the section in which the row is, then use this code

```
let indexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: row, inSection: section)
```

For accessing the cell corresponding to this indexPath, use

```
let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! tableViewCell
```